# Unable to import/link table from SQL Server into access. Too many indexes error

Tags: indexing, ms-access-2010, importerror

I am trying to import a table from SQL into access but I am getting too many indexes in the table error. The table in SQL is indexed to several tables and unfortunately I don't have the rights to modify or change the table anyway. just have read access in the DB. I am trying to import/link the table but I am unable to do so due to too many indexes error being thrown.

Is it possible to only import/link the data and not indexes? I know access has a limit of 32 indexes. I have cleared auto indexes in options too, but I still get the error.

Is there a solution as to how I can import/link this table in access?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I did some digging on how to avoid this problem. So the problem is we can't directly link to the SQL database if the table has a lot of indexes and Access will throw an error "too many indexes on the table you are trying to import".

one way to beat this is by putting together a "Pass-through query". Lot of people suggested VBA code. I am not a coder and could not get it to work effectively. However, Access gives you the capability to build it with out VBA and the solution I found was in Microsoft website.

The steps are as follows: you might have to work around it for 2010 due to different naming convention when compared to 2007.

On the Create tab, click **Query Design** in the Other group.
Click **Close** in the Show Table dialog box without adding any tables or queries.
Save the query. Open the Query in design mode
On the Design tab, click **Pass-Through** in the Query Type workgroup.
Click Property Sheet in the Show/Hide workgroup to display the property sheet for the query.
In the query property sheet, place the mouse pointer in the ODBC Connect Str property, and then, click the Build (...) button.

With the ODBC Connect Str property, you specify information about the database to which you want to connect. You can type the connection information, or click Build, and then enter information about the server to which you are connecting.

When you are prompted to save the password in the connection string, click **Yes** if you want the password and logon name to be stored in the connection string information.
If the query is not the type that returns records, set the ReturnsRecords property to **No.**
In the SQL Pass-Through Query window, type your pass-through query. For example, the following pass-through query uses the Microsoft SQL Server TOP operator in the SELECT statement to return only the first 25 orders in the Orders table from the sample Northwind database:
*SELECT TOP 25 orderid from orders*

To run the query, click **Run** in the Results group on the Design tab. For a SQL pass-through query that returns records, click **Datasheet** view on the status bar.
If necessary, Microsoft Access prompts you for information about your server database.

This worked for me. If some one is having the same problem you can use these steps.